# Error: filter not found - when watching for latest blocks

Tags: go-ethereum, web3js

```
Found block 3258499
Found block 3258502
Found block 3258587
Error: filter not found
    at Object.InvalidResponse (/home/ubuntu/node_modules/web3/lib/web3/errors.js:35:16)
    at /home/ubuntu/node_modules/web3/lib/web3/requestmanager.js:255:40
    at Array.filter (native)
    at /home/ubuntu/node_modules/web3/lib/web3/requestmanager.js:252:12
    at XMLHttpRequest.request.onreadystatechange (/home/ubuntu/node_modules/web3/lib/web3/httpprovider.js:118:13)
    at XMLHttpRequestEventTarget.dispatchEvent (/home/ubuntu/node_modules/xhr2/lib/xhr2.js:64:18)
    at XMLHttpRequest._setReadyState (/home/ubuntu/node_modules/xhr2/lib/xhr2.js:354:12)
    at XMLHttpRequest._onHttpResponseEnd (/home/ubuntu/node_modules/xhr2/lib/xhr2.js:509:12)
    at IncomingMessage.<anonymous> (/home/ubuntu/node_modules/xhr2/lib/xhr2.js:469:24)
    at emitNone (events.js:91:20)
    at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:186:7)
    at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:974:12)
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:74:11)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:98:9)
```

I receive the above error when using this filter. Note that it works successfully for several blocks before failing

```
var filter = web3.eth.filter({toBlock:'latest', address: '0xexampleaddress', 'topics':[web3.sha3('Trade(uint256,address,uint256,address)')]});

filter.watch(function(error, logs) {
  console.log('Found block' + logs.blockNumber);
}
```

Comment: When you say "works successfully", do you mean it returns a few events, or a few blocks go by without error and it crashes when it sees an event? For the address filter to work, you would have to have the address indexed in the event emitter, like ... event(address indexed msg.sender);

Comment: I believe the latter. Essentially I'm only looking for transactions for a given address and topic. Do you have an example of indexing the address in the event emitter using .watch?

Comment: Did you manage to solve this issue? I have a similar problem. I receive a few events 100% and then suddenly I receive the same error that you have continuously. I am using Web3 version 0.19.1.

Comment: Same issue with `github:shayanb/web3.js#develop`. Any news?